# How to print following json data using foreach in php(coinmarket api)

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to print the following json data in foreach loop of php. Can anyone please tell me how I can do it? I have searched a lot but nothing works.
I am getting this data from coinmarket api and printing this code by using:
  but failed to get every value separately.

```
$curl = curl_init(); // Get cURL resource
    // Set cURL options
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $request,            // set the request URL
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,     // set the headers 
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1         // ask for raw response instead of bool
    ));
  $response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
    print_r(json_decode($response));
```

Below is code that I want to use in foreach loop:

```
stdClass Object ( [status] => stdClass Object ( [timestamp] => 2019-10-09T03:13:30.051Z [error_code] => 0 [error_message] => [elapsed] => 9 [credit_count] => 1 [notice] => ) [data] => stdClass Object ( [BTC] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => Bitcoin [symbol] => BTC [slug] => bitcoin [num_market_pairs] => 7935 [date_added] => 2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z [tags] => Array ( [0] => mineable ) [max_supply] => 21000000 [circulating_supply] => 17981825 [total_supply] => 17981825 [platform] => [cmc_rank] => 1 [last_updated] => 2019-10-09T03:12:33.000Z [quote] => stdClass Object ( [USD] => stdClass Object ( [price] => 8195.0290967 [volume_24h] => 14981665979.667 [percent_change_1h] => -0.224992 [percent_change_24h] => -1.35388 [percent_change_7d] => -1.38135 [market_cap] => 147361579086.77 [last_updated] => 2019-10-09T03:12:33.000Z ) ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please format your question, code and output so it's becomming readable. What have you tried yet? What data do you need?

To get a list of the names of all coins retrieved in data you can use this code:

```
$response = json_decode($response);

foreach ($response->data as $coin){ // assuming the data could contain multiple coins
    echo $coin->name;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Tip: if you want to see a nice formatted output of print_r() in an HTML-page you can place it between PRE-tags.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_object);
echo '</pre>';
```